# Sorting rows in MySql based on algebra on two or more columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am designing a Test-System for a school.The table is like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Student_id  | Total Questions  |     Questions Attempted   |    Correct     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     36         |       60         |           42              |       20      
     19         |       60         |           38              |       32
     119        |       60         |           37              |       31
```

Now, marking scheme is `+3` for correct and `-1` for wrong

Number of wrong questions will be calculated as `wrong = attempted - correct`

**Questions**

1) I want to give the give the student some points based on their ranks, so I want to sort the table on the decreasing order of their score `i.e. score = 3 * correct - wrong`.Though,I could have stored the score as well but since it is redundant data I don't want to store it into the table.How can I sort the table using SQL query.

2)When I will be updating the points of students based on their performance into the table `student`,I am picking `student_id` from `result` table and making updations into the `student` table i.e. 1 query per student.This means that if 4000 students sat for the test ,4000 queries !!! .Can I improve the situation (minimise queries)?

**EDIT**

Student schema for question 2

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Student_id   |    fname    |   lname    |    contact      |     points
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Regarding question (2) could you provide the student schema?

Answer (score 3):

1. you can just specify what you want in the sort

   ```
   select student_id,correct, attempted,field4,field5, (3 * correct - (attempted-correct)) as score 
   from students sort by score desc
   ```
2. yes, take a look at [bulk update](http://blog.bubble.ro/how-to-make-multiple-updates-using-a-single-query-in-mysql/) of sql, you can prepare the query and update 10 by 10 or 100 by 100, but not too much since sql command have limit on its length

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1.**

Supposing the table is named Results, and that Student_id is unique, here is a possible solution to your question:

```
SELECT Results.*, (3*Correct-(Total_Questions-Correct)) AS score
FROM Results
ORDER BY score DESC
```

**Question 2.**

Supposing the Students are already added to the table Students, or that they already have a score, this is a possible SQL Query to update the students table without making the 4k queries:

```
UPDATE StudentsTable AS s
INNER JOIN PointsTable AS p
ON s.Student_id = p.Student_id
SET
    s.Points = s.Points + (3 * p.Correct - (p.Questions_Attempted - p.Correct))
```

If you need to perform more tests in the future you can add a Test_ID column to you Points Table and then add a WHERE clause to the UPDATE query in order to just add up the score from a given test.

**Optimization**

You can optimize the queries a little bit by changing the way you calculate the score:

```
SELECT Results.*, (2*Correct-Total_Questions) AS score
FROM Results
ORDER BY score DESC

UPDATE StudentsTable AS s
INNER JOIN PointsTable AS p
ON s.Student_id = p.Student_id
SET
    s.Points = s.Points + (2 * p.Correct - p.Questions_Attempted)
```

Answer (score 0):

To rank students by score you can do

```sql
SELECT student_id,
(
  SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
    FROM student_results
   WHERE 3 * correct - (total - correct) >=
         3 * r.correct - (r.total - r.correct)
     AND student_id <> r.student_id
) rank
  FROM student_results r
```

Output:

```
| STUDENT_ID | RANK |
|------------|------|
|         36 |    3 |
|         19 |    1 |
|        119 |    2 |
```

Now you can update student points in one go using multi-table `UPDATE` syntax instead of hitting the database with number of update queries.

```sql
UPDATE students s JOIN
(
  SELECT student_id,
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
      FROM student_results
     WHERE 3 * correct - (total - correct) >=
           3 * r.correct - (r.total - r.correct)
       AND student_id <> r.student_id
  ) rank
    FROM student_results r
) q
    ON s.student_id = q.student_id
   SET s.points = s.points + 
       CASE q.rank  -- implement your logic of translating ranks to points here
          WHEN 1 THEN 100
          WHEN 2 THEN  50
          WHEN 3 THEN  10
          ELSE 0
       END;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a807b/2)** demo